# How to write if and else in jquery remote validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to add a if condition in remote method ,hence for the form which doesn't have $('#emailUrl').val(),will fall into else condition

```
rules : {           

    lastName : {
        required : true,
        namevalidation : true
    },
    // Remote is the jquery function to check unique character using URL
    primaryEmailId : {
        required : true,
        email : true,
        remote : { 
            // If Condition required here. Please suggest me
            url : $('#emailUrl').val(),
            data: {
                primaryEmailId: function() {
                    return $("#primaryEmailId").val();  
                },
            }
       },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is use a `depends` and `param` in your remote rule.  They are described somewhat in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules), but it isn't clear that it would work for remote (it does!).

So taking your example, you'd rework it to look like this:

```
primaryEmailId : {
    required : true,
    email : true,
    remote : { 
      //if this returns true, remote will be triggered
      depends: function(){
        return $('#emailUrl').val() != '';
      },
      //using these parameters
      param: {
        url : 'your validation url.php',
        data: {
            primaryEmailId: function() {
                return $("#primaryEmailId").val();  
            },
        }
      }
   },
}
```

The only part I'm not clear on is why you want to call different URLs depending on the user?  Hopefully the important part was more about how to call remote or not :)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/w5urs2h8/) (note that jsfiddle is a bit weird about ajax calls so mine is a bit more complex).

Answer (score 0):

You can not put condition on the url, You need to define function and then need to put condition. I am not sure what happen if you pass blank URL for remote validation. Please check below solution.

```
lastName : {
                    required : true,
                    namevalidation : true
                },
                // Remote is the jquery function to check unique character using URL
                primaryEmailId : {
                    required : true,
                    email : true,
                    remote : { 
                      // If Condition required here. Please suggest me
                        url : function (){
                        if (typeof ($('#emailUrl').val()) != 'undefined')
                            {
                                return $('#emailUrl').val();
                            } else {
                                return '';
                            }

                        },
                        data: {
                            primaryEmailId: function() {
                                            return $("#primaryEmailId").val();
                                        },
                                    }
                            },
                },
```

Comment: Did you try that?  I don't believe that the `url` field of `$.post` accepts a function, instead it is treated as a string.

Comment: Is it possible to write if condition in JQUERY validations Rules to validate only for particular fields. Please suggest me

Comment: i have used condition in mycode like below

https://jsfiddle.net/073qz3u9/

i hope this will help you and getting my point